# Detailed guide on how to Create a Litecoin Fork, With Pre-mine instructions

Tags: litecoin, altcoin, blockchain-fork

I need a Detailed guide on how to Create a Litecoin Fork, With Pre-mine instructions, I would be very grateful if someone posted a comprehensive guide on how to Create a Litecoin software fork, with a Pre-mine.

Comment: You have to create value before you can divide it up.

Comment: I'm also interested to know how to form an altcoin to play around with. Which is why I'm learning the basics. What level of skill in C++ have you got? What's the project's goal? What can others learn from this? Any coding section of SE would shoot this down for those reasons as it really feels like a "someone do my homework" query which doesn't sit well on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz no that's where we come in

Comment: This is not easy when every time this question gets asked in some form there's never any follow up info from the OP's solitary post! @Wonker, details?

Comment: @wonker  tell me your email id or skypeid?

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head:

- You need a new genesis block.
- You need a different address byte (e.g. bitcoin uses 0).
- You need to change the default port and rpc port.
- You need a way for clients to find one another. You can run a DNS seed.
- You need to change the "backup client list" which is a bunch of 32 bit integers which represent IP addresses.
- You need somebody to mine initially, because otherwise transactions won't confirm.
- You need to alter the default datadir directory.
- You need to change the magic number in the protocol header, otherwise your client might connect to the Litecoin network by accident, wasting bandwidth.
- You need to change the alert keys, otherwise the Litecoin devs can send alerts onto your network.
- Add a transaction to the UTXDB which is your premine transaction

That's all I can think of, though obviously you'd want to change GUI elements to the actual name of your currency.

Comment: Someone remind OP of the service which makes clone coins using a website where you put in block time and algorithm and total coin supply in exchange for the new icon-ed version of *Litecoin*?

Comment: @AussieCryptocurrency This? http://coincreator.net/